# Error en android java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una *app* para *Android*, y parte de mi código es como el siguiente:

```
public void loop(){

   for(Car car:carList)
        car.run();

}
```

Lo malo es que obtengo el error `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. Estuve investigando, usé iteradores y la notación de java **synchronized**, porque según leí en la documentación de *Oracle*, el error puede generarse por varios *threads* usando mi método "loop".

```
public synchronized void loop(){
 Iterator<Car> carIterator = carList.iterator();
 while(cardIterator.hasNext()){
  carIterator.next().run();
 }
}
```

Realmente no sé qué más pueda solucionar este problema. Uso la clase de este método y este mismo, más que todo, en servicios *background* y en *activities*, también las uso (usando el patrón *singleton* para instanciar) .

---

Gracias chicos por el apoyo! 
Bueno, para dar más detalles de mi problema, el carList es un ArrayList con objetos **Car** 
Mi clase car es la siguiente:

```
public class Car{
   private int mSpeed;
   private int mDistance; //inicializo con cero
    ........
   public void run(){
       mSpeed=getRandomSpeed();
       mDistance+=mSpeed;
       updateDistanceInDB();//Aquí lo guardo en una base de dato sqlite
   }
   .........   

}
```

-El error me indica que este se generó en la línea donde ejecuto el método **run()** dentro del loop. Además, lo que me extraña es que este error no sucede en otro celular que tengo.
-Este es el la página de la documentación oficial de oracle que me dice que el error puede deberse a varios threads usando mi lista, por eso use **synchronized** pero no solucionó

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

¿porqué en otros móviles funcionará y otros no?
Gracias chicos por su ayuda!

Comment: Para ayudarte, vamos a necesitar lo siguiente: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). También, incluye el stack trace que acompaña el error..

Comment: Sería de gran utilidad ver la implementación del método run en la clase Car para poder dar una respuesta.

Comment: Carlos, puedes resolver este problema simplemente realizando una copia de tu List y con esta realizar la operación, agregue respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

> porque según leí en la documentación de Oracle, el error puede generarse por varios threads usando mi método "loop".

No es correcto. Lo que dice la excepción es que:

1. Has creado un iterador (bueno, la sintaxis del for lo hace por tí)
2. Entre llamada y llamada al `next()` del iterador, el contenido del `Collection` original se ha modificado (básicamente, alguien ha llamado a `add()`, `remove()` o `reset()`). Realmente, no importa que sea desde otro thread o desde el mismo (¿seguro que el método `run()` no modifica la lista?). Al hacer la siguiente llamada al `next()`, salta la excepción.

Posibles soluciones:

1) Identifica qué otro código está modificando la colección, y pon tu `loop` y el otro código en una sección crítica (`synchronized`), usando el mismo objeto de `lock`.

Nota que si estás modificando la lista desde el mismo *thread* (por ejemplo desde el método `run()`), la sincronización no ayuda (la sincronización evita que dos threads ejecuten bloques de código que se interfieren entre sí a la vez; si es culpa del `run()` estarás dentro del mismo *thread*).

2) Si no quieres/puedes con 1), haz un nuevo `Collection` con los contenidos del original e itera sobre éste; `List<Car> listCopy = new ArrayList<>(carList);`.

El principal problema de este enfoque es que no sabes cuál es la causa original del problema, con lo cual no sabes si tendrías que actualizar la lista porque la lista original ha cambiado.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar el error:

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Lo que comentas
"el error puede generarse por varios threads usando mi método "loop"."
Es en parte cierto pero **lo que en realidad sucede es que tu lista esta siendo modificada y al mismo tiempo esta siendo usada probablemente en otro thread**

Puedes resolver este problema simplemente creando una copia de tu List en este caso `carList`:

```
List<Car> copiaList = new ArrayList<Car>(carList);
```

En esta copia puedes realizar las operaciones sin problema y evitaras el error `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: No necesariamente. Revisa la documentación de [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html): "The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException."